# Access form does not display records on click event

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form (Vendor_Update) that works perfectly. The form is simple - an unbound combo box (cbo_Vendor) is used to filter 4 textboxs for editing. The form is bound to tbl_Vendors. A macro is used on the OnChange event for cbo_Vendor to search for the selected record in tbl_Vendors. I can edit the textboxes and they save to the table, as intended.
I want to open the Vendor_Update form by clicking a button on another form (Form_Start) in my database. I added Cmd_Vendor_Data to the start form with this code in VBA:

```
Private Sub Cmd_Vendor_Data_Click()
  DoCmd.OpenForm "Vendor_Update", acNormal, "", "", acFormAdd
End Sub
```

The form opens, and I can select a vendor from the combo box, but the text boxes do not populate with the information from tbl_Vendors.

Why does the Vendor_Update form work when I open it exclusively, but not when it is opened by a click event?

One additional note for the Vendor_Update form - this code is in the On Load event:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  If Not Me.NewRecord Then RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
  Me.Cbo_Vendor.Requery  
End Sub
```

I am not well-versed in VBA, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want.  If you change `acFormAdd` to `acFormEdit` ... is that what you want?

Comment: Shouldn't your requery code be in the `Cmd_Vendor_Data_Click()` sub? Did you try instantiating the `Vendor_Update` form and then calling its requery method from the parent form?

Comment: acFormEdit worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @HansUp for the assistance!  Code corrected and form works as intended.

```
Private Sub Cmd_Vendor_Data_Click()
  DoCmd.OpenForm "Vendor_Update", acNormal, "", "", acFormEdit
End Sub
```